# Controlling objects on another View/Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I have 2 ViewControllers with separate classes.  On the first view i have a switch, on that switch i want to be able to click that switch and hide some objects that is on the other view.   But the issue i am running in, is being able to use the objects on the other class.  I have imported both header files on each method and i'm still not being able to use the objects that is on the second viewcontroller to the first viewcontroller.

Let's say I have a label on the first viewcontroller and create a outlet for it and call it "ice" on the first method file, now i want to be able to call and use ice on the other viewcontroller/method.  So i can do something like

```
ice.hide = true
```

on the other method file.   But i get an error when i type in 'ice' like 'ice' doens't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have some options in iOS in order to achieve your goal. Provided both view controller views are loaded and on the screen or if using navigation controller then in the stack then the following options would work:

1. Use an `NSNotification` and send the information between the two `UIViewController` instances.
2. Use the `delegate` pattern to send messages between by calling specific methods in the delegate.
3. Pass a code block from one to the other and when an action occurs the code block can be called and perform the updates you require.

Of the options `NSNotification` is good for de-coupling however it can be cumbersome if you have lots of notifications around the application.
Delegate is a documented approach and is widely used in iOS hence would look into it.
Completion code block is used and more swift like but can cause you issues if you have scope variables being kept and thus possibility of cyclic retain cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Don't do that. It violates the principle of encapsulation, and important idea in object oriented programming. (It *is* possible, but such a bad idea that I'm not going to explain how to do it.)

What you should do is add public methods or properties in your view controller and in the implementation of those, alter your user interface.

Say you have a VC (ViewController) that displays news articles and it has a title label and a body field.

Instead of trying to alter the titleLabel or bodyField directly, add NNString properties `title` and `body`. In the setters for those properties, save the new value, and also try to display it to your VCs views. I say "try" because an outside caller may invoke your property setters before your VC's views have been loaded. You will also want to install the property values to your views in your viewWillAppear method.

Once you've set up properties or methods that let you change the settings of your VC, you can make it so that outside code is not so tightly coupled to your view controller.

With the approach above, and outside view controller has to have the header file of your view controller to #import at compile time, and can only talk to that kind of view controller.

Say instead that in the example of the news article view controller we have several different types of view controllers that have title and body fields, but that they inherit from different base classes.

You could define a `protocol`, which is a defined set of methods, and have your different view controllers "conform to" that protocol. This is like creating a specialized language, and having certain view controllers say "I understand that language".

Then an outside object can set the title or body property on any object that conforms to your protocol, without knowing or caring what kind of object it is.

The delegate pattern, mentioned in darren's answer, is an example of using a protocol to create loose coupling between objects.